# Authorization with respect to React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to implement authorization at the frontend level, and I'm making use of react-router. The code that I've come up with has been attached below. My questions are:

1.) Can we conditionally render/remove `<Switch>` and `<Route>`

2.) Why the below code does not work, even when I hit /user in my browser it redirects me to /dashboard (/dashboard is the value stored in noMatchUrl variable when a token exists otherwise /login is stored)

Any help is deeply appreciated

I've searched on the internet but have not found anything that is even barely close to my scenario

```
{
    token
    ?
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route exact path="/tasks" component={Tasks} />
        <Route exact path="/lists" component={Lists} />
        <Route exact path="/user" component={User} />
        <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
        <Route render={() => (<Redirect to={noMatchUrl} />)} />
    </Switch>
    :
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path={["/reset-password/:token", "/set-password/:token"]} component={ResetPassword} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/forgot-password" component{ForgotPassword}/>
        <Route render={() => (<Redirect to={noMatchUrl} />)} />
    </Switch>
}
```

I expect that the authorization works correctly, but now even normal routing does not work as explained in above

Comment: It should work. Are you getting any error?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, I just wanted to know whether this is the right approach for implementing authorisation

Comment: There was one error related to incorrect routing which has been resolved now, so my current question relates to the way in which I have implemented authorisation

Comment: Yes. You can go ahead with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a ternary statement between routers. I suggest you make use of some sort of privateroute component where you check for the token and then return a component if it passes or redirect upon failure like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Auth from '../../Modules/Auth';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (

    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
      Auth.isUserAuthenticated() === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/login',
            state: { from: props.location }
          }} />
    )} />
  )

  export default PrivateRoute;
```

Then in the Auth file being imported write a class that checks for the token however it may be:

```
class Auth {

    /**
     * Authenticate a user. Save a token string in Local Storage
     *
     * @param {string} token
     */
    static authenticateUser(token) {
      localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    }

    /**
     * Check if a user is authenticated - check if a token is saved in Local Storage
     *
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    static isUserAuthenticated() {
      return localStorage.getItem('token') !== null;
    }

    /**
     * Deauthenticate a user. Remove a token from Local Storage.
     *
     */
    static deauthenticateUser() {
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
    }

    /**
     * Get a token value.
     *
     * @returns {string}
     */

    static getToken() {
      return localStorage.getItem('token');
    }

  }

  export default Auth;
```

Then in your switch you could write something like:

```
<Switch>
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/tasks" component={Tasks} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/lists" component={Lists} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/user" component={User} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
        <Route exact path={["/reset-password/:token", "/set-password/:token"]} component={ResetPassword} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/forgot-password" component{ForgotPassword}/>
        <Route render={() => (<Redirect to={noMatchUrl} />)} />
</Switch>
```